# Domain name from IP

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

My site still gets requests from one IP address - 195.210.29.12.

When I tried nslookup for that it shown me 
Name:    data12.websupport.sk
Address:  195.210.29.12

That is the hostname of one hosting provider. When I tried to realize which domain it is by using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/ it gave ma about 500 results.

My question is - is it possible to realize which domain it was?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Provider has an abuse Mailbox. If anyone tries to hack you page or sth like that, you can write a mail to the Provider. In this case following mail to:

```
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@websupport.sk
```

Comment: Thanks Oli. I will use that.